# Getting the profile2 user fields?

Tags: 7, users

i am writing a simple multistep form using ctools on drupal 7. Everything seems to work but i have a one last problem before i finish the task. How can i access the custom user fields (or fieldset i am not sure about the terminology). I've tried to do that by using the function below but it doesn't works and the property is always empty;

```
function helper_get_default_value_from_profile($fieldset, $key){

  $uid      = helper_is_user_logged_in();
  $account  = user_load($uid);
  $profile  = profile2_load_by_user($account, "cv");

  if(!property_exists($profile, $fieldset))
    return 0;

  if(empty($profile->$fieldset))
    return 0;

  $fieldset_ref = $profile->$fieldset;
  $id           = $fieldset_ref["und"][0]["value"];
  $fieldset_data = field_collection_field_get_entity($id);

  if(!property_exists($fieldset_data, $key))
    return 0;

  if(empty($fieldset_data->$key))
    return 0;

  $user_prop = $fieldset_data->$key;
  return $user_prop["und"][0]["value"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to retrieve the value of a single field from a field collection. And that the field collection you want to retrieve a field from is a field of a 'cv' profile2.

The returned value of `profile2_load_by_user($account, "cv");` is a `Profile` entity object. When `$fieldset` is the (machine) name of a field collection field, then you can retrieve its value using `$items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, $fieldset)` (see [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7)). This will return an array of field collection values (or `FALSE` if there is no value for the field). The values are arrays containing a `value` entry which is the entity id of a field collection entity. You can load the field collection entity for an ID using `field_collection_field_get_entity()`. Finally, using `$key` as field name, you can retrieve the values of one of this field collection entity's fields using `field_get_items()` again.

```
$items = field_get_items('profile2', $profile, $fieldset);
if ($items) {
  $item = reset($items);
  if (!empty($item['value'])) {
    $field_collection = field_collection_field_get_entity($item);
    if ($field_collection) {
      $items = field_get_items('field_collection', $field_collection, $key);
      if ($items) {
        $item = reset($items);
        return !empty($item['value']) ? $item['value'] : 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
return 0;
```